# xcode large simulator on external Display

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I am using MacBook Pro 13 Early 2011 with external display 24' connected via thunderbolt port
But I have some issue with iPhone Simulator it running originally in large mode. How I can fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean "Retina" with "large mode"? Just pick "Hardware", "Device" and then a "non retina version" from the top bar, when the simulator is running ;-)

Comment: @d4Rk But Can I use retina in my case?

Comment: Why not? If your screen's resolution is not big enough, you may have to scroll a lot, but you can use it :-)

Comment: @d4Rk Thanks. I understand I should use scale :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

#### 1. Make it non-Retina

This is done in <kbd>Hardware</kbd> > <kbd>Device</kbd>, and will simply change the resolution of the screen your app is running on.

[image]

#### 2. Scale It

<kbd>Window</kbd> > <kbd>Zoom</kbd>, keeps the Retina-ness of the screen, but scales the simulator itself down to fit on your screen - very useful.

[image]

Comment: I know this solution. It's not right solution. And I have wrote it above

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it's might be some Apple's bug with simulators. SO I have opened a ticket in Apple Bug Report to fix this issue

I should wait for their answer